# Reading a file using python 3.x not skipping blank lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read a file and simply skip the blank lines. from some reason it doesn't really skip the empty lines. what am i doing wrong?:

```
ourFile = 'File.txt'
with open(ourFile) as fp:
    for tmpLine in fp:
        currentLine = tmpLine.strip()
        if currentLine != '\n' and currentLine != '\r\n':
             print(currentLine)
```

Comment: `.strip()` removes `\r\n` characters by default (when calling without arguments). So check for `if currentLine:`

Comment: Ev.Konis => your solution worked. how do i close the ticket and mark your answer as solution?

Comment: Mark the one by @schwobaseggl. it is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) strips any whitespace, including line breaks `'\n'` or carriage returns `'\r'`:

```
currentLine = tmpLine.strip()
if currentLine != '':
    print(currentLine)
# or simply:
if currentLine:
    print(currentLine)
```

For a rough orientation which characters get stripped by default, you can look at [`string.whitespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.whitespace):

```
import string
string.whitespace
# '\t\n\x0b\x0c\r '
```

Comment: `if currentLine:` should suffice.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Was just about to add that :) Wanted to first pick the OP up where he was.